# Get location in HuaweiMap flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, huawei-map-kit

In my app i use Huawei map. I want get location, but `locationService` return `Location` with all nullable property.

I don't have idea what i do wrong.

Code to get location:

```
      var permissionHandler = PermissionHandler();
      var status = await permissionHandler.hasLocationPermission();
      if (!status) {
        return null;
      }
      var locationService = FusedLocationProviderClient();
      var locationRequest = LocationRequest();
      locationRequest.interval = 5000;
      var locationSettingsRequest = LocationSettingsRequest(
        requests: [LocationRequest()],
        alwaysShow: true,
        needBle: false,
      );
      var locationSettingState = await locationService.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest);

      if (locationSettingState.locationPresent) {
        await locationService.getLastLocation().then((_locationData) async {
          print("Location: $_locationData");
        }).catchError((onError) {
          print(onError);
        });
      }
```

print output:
`Location: Location(provider: null, latitude: null, longitude: null, altitude: null, speed: null, bearing: null, horizontalAccuracyMeters: null, verticalAccuracyMeters: null, speedAccuracyMetersPerSecond: null, bearingAccuracyDegrees: null, time: null, elapsedRealtimeNanos: null)`

Comment: Could you please share the detail log info and test device? Huawei_map does not provide the Location interface. You can integrate [huawei_location](https://pub.dev/packages/huawei_location).

Comment: In addition, you may be using the wrong API. `locationService.getLastLocation` is used to obtain the last location. You can use [requestLocationUpdates](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-References-V1/fused-location-client-0000001050179418-V1#section1497020201411) to continuously request location updates.

Comment: I solved this. I don't use ```await locationService.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest)``` <- this reload location and return coordinates